# Sex with a gentile on her period

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, sexuality, niddah

In terms of transgression and/or liability: is there a difference between a Jewish male having sex with a gentile woman who is in the midst of menstruating, and a gentile woman that is not in the midst of menstruating?

Do the laws of Niddah apply to gentiles?

Comment: The Gemara Avodah Zara  36B states that any sexual relations with a non Jew are rabbinically considered to have transgressed the sin of nidah. Rashi explains that biblically they can’t become a nidda but the rabbis gave them that status https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.36b.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Rashi

Comment: Worth noting that relations with a non-Jew (whether or not she has had her period) incurs *karet midivrei kabbalah* (*karet* from the prophetic tradition). See Rambam Hilchot Issurei Biah 12:6 https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twelve.htm

Comment: The short answer is -- no it doesn't.

Comment: Based on the question, which definitely falls within the domain of being “on topic” for Mi Yodeya together with the status of the poster as a “new contributor”, simply loading on votes to close their question doesn’t seem very nice or welcoming.  The 2 opening comments seem to be good beginnings for potential answers. Welcome Nossiee & thank you for your question to Mi Yodeya . If you haven’t seen it yet, you may find it helpful to click on the “Tour” link in order to see what the site is trying to do.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The close votes presumably preceded the most recent edit...

Comment: @JoelK Possibly. But if the question has been improved and falls into the domain of a good question, those individuals who voted to close need to remember to remove their negative votes. Comments & actions are intended to improve, not to injure. Like Hillel says in Avot 1:12, “Be like the students of Aharon, love peace, pursue peace, love mankind and draw them to the Torah.” Like the Gra explains, “peace” שלום, has a connotation of maintaining diverse & even conflicting views and people.

Comment: The words are a little fancier and less personal now, but it was a good question even at the beginning.